# No matching function for call (3 arguments expected, 0 actual). Dealing with vectors and strings in C++ for the first time

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to write a program that gets bigger and smaller depending on the data from the text file. There are three functions that have specific instructions. This is my first project using vectors so I have been pretty confused. At first I was getting a lot of error messages but I have cut it down to only one error in the compiler.

The error I am getting is that in the Insert function there is no matching function to call and that the candidate expects 3 arguments but there is none. I have googled the error and I have read that I might need a constructor but I can't seem to set it up correctly. I see that I need to edit my code to pass three arguments, but I'm not sure if I am supposed to do that in the function below or in main.

Another thought is that I might be passing the wrong type which I googled could be the error. This could be possible as I haven't used vector and might not be passing the types correctly. I am also calling by reference which might not be the right thing to do.

If someone could help me out I would appreciate the help. I've been fixing my errors for the past few hours with Google but can't seem to fix this final error(which admittedly could be because of several errors). Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void insertFunction(vector<string>, string, int);
void deleteFunction(vector<string>, int);
void printFunction(vector<string>);
int main()
{
  vector<string> V;
  string command, word;
  int position;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("data_2.txt");
  if(!fin){
    cout << "The file doesn't exist " << endl;
  }
  else {
    while (fin >> command){
      if (command == "Insert"){
         fin >> word;
         fin >> position;
         insertFunction(V, word, position);
       }
        else if (command == "Delete"){
         fin >> position;
         deleteFunction(V, position);
            }
        else if (command == "Print"){
         printFunction(V);
            }
        else{
         cout << "Error! Command is not recognized" << endl;
        }
        }
    }

  return 0;
}

void insertFunction(vector<string>& V, string position, int word){
  V.insert();
}
void deleteFunction(vector<string>& V, int position){
  V.erase(V.begin()+position);
}
void printFunction(vector<string>& V){
  for(int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++){
      cout << V[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your parameter types reversed in `insertFunction`? Shouldnt it be `int position, string word`. Also your prototype declarations at the top dont match your function definitions. The prototypes don't have a reference argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
V.insert();
```

The `insert()` method is a very sociable method. It wants to talk to its parameters. It likes its parameters. Its parameters are `insert()`'s best friends.

But because you did not provide any suitable set of parameters to `insert()`, you just made this method very, very sad. It is very lonely.

If you would like to make your `insert()` method happy, please introduce it to some nice, polite, friendly parameters. Like the position where to insert something, and what that something is.

Comment: `v.begin()` gives you the beginning iterator. `position` is a `std::string`. I don't blame your compiler for getting indigestion if you ask it to add a string to an iterator. That is one recipe for a major gastric upset. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify the size of your vector:

```
    vector<string> V(MAX_SIZE);
```

MAX_SIZE could be fixed or can be obtained from file.
Simply you can use `[]` operator to insert new elements:

```
    void insertFunction(vector<string>& V, int position, string word) {
    V[position]= word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It now compiles but when I run it becomes a segmentation fault and doesn't run. I am assuming it has to do with memory so possibly the size of my vector. If I am bringing in 20 lines from the text file, should I just set a constant (or the size of the vector) to 20? And is the segmentation fault due to this?